# How to return *result without using result[0], result[1]

Tags: python, list, variables, return, arguments

Is there a way I can return a list of lists without explicitly accessing the list by index? I would like to just return something like return *result. How can I do that in python?

```
def func():
    result = [[1,2],[3,4]] 
    return result[0], result[1] # I want to return *result 

print(func)
```

EDIT: I can't just return the result because I need to return each element, not the whole list as there are constraints. Also I wouldn't know how big the results are. so it could be up to return[100]

Comment: Why not simply `return result`? If you want to return that as a tuple for some reason, `return tuple(result)`?

Comment: Just `return result`. You can then do `first_pair, second_pair = func()`.

Comment: Either way, you're going to get a sequence; what does it matter if that sequence is a tuple or a list?

Comment: `*result` by itself is not an expression; it's a fragment of the syntax, e.g., for a list display like `[*result, 5]`.

Answer (score 1):

return a [`tuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple):

```
def func():
    result = [[1,2],[3,4]] 
    return tuple(result)
```

output: `([1, 2], [3, 4])`

Comment: Did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: There is no problem here. The essence of using commas to separate multiple return values is to return a tuple, just as this answer does.

Answer (score 1):

This is not allowed in python. Python does now allow returning multiple things. The way python does it is by wrapping them in a tuple. For your example:

```py
def func():
    result = [[1,2],[3,4]] 
    return result[0], result[1]

def func2():
    result = [[1,2],[3,4]] 
    return tuple(result)

print(type(func())) # prints tuple
print(type(func2())) # prints tuple
```

You can get the individual elements back by unwrapping the return value of the function call. Here is an example:

```py
print(func()) # prints ([1, 2], [3, 4])
print(func2()) # prints ([1, 2], [3, 4])

print(*func()) # prints [1, 2] [3, 4]
print(*func2()) # prints [1, 2] [3, 4]
```

I would recommend to simply return the list as is. The only benefit I see for making it a tuple is that tuples are immutable, if that is something you need then `return tuple(result)`.